# When an unhandled rejected promise throw its Error

Tags: javascript, promise

What I thought is that at a point where a *pending* promise changes its state to a *rejected* promise a **rejection handler** should be queued in, otherwise the promise throws an Error. but it's not the case when I do that

```
Promise.reject("error"); //or new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("error"))
//.
//.
//.
console.log("end of script");
```

the output will be

```
//end of script
//Uncaught (in promise) error
```

So my question is when unhandled rejected promises throw their error ? 
Thanks

**EDIT**

My question is about the time of throwing error due to an absence of rejection handler(s) in that rejected promise even that the process is Sync

```
console.log(new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("error")))
//prints 'Promise {<rejected>: "error"}' not pending because it ran synchronously
```

so in

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("error"))   //(1)

console.log("end of script");
```

why line (1) not throwing error before printing *'end of script'*

Comment: pretty sure the `Promise.reject` function is asynchronous, so it doesn't necessary run before other code unless you use a control structure (e.g. `try/catch`)

Comment: I updated my question to be Sync also

Comment: your updated question is roughly the same as your original question. As I said, I'm pretty sure `Promise.reject` is asynchronous, so it might not run in the order you expect unless you use a control structure.

Comment: I guess it throws always error whenever you write Promise.reject. For internal code there is a library called bluebird you can take a look for this https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.js

Comment: Promise.reject is synchronous.

Comment: Jhecht and KiwiRupela Benjamin Gruenbaum thanks for your efforts

Comment: Happy to help, we also have docs on this in the Node.js guides section which is free on our websites and docs for the process hooks ;]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is when unhandled rejected promises throw their error ? Thanks

Hey, I worked on some of this. Basically: it's implementation defined. At Node we do (and Chrome does the same):

- When a promise is rejected if there is no catch handler
- Wait for a microtick (so all `.then`s and `nextTick`s and `enqueueMicrotask`s are done).
- if no one handled it by then and *before* any I/O mark it as unhandled and fire an unhandledrejection event.

So in your case it happens after the log, but before any I/O or setTimeouts.

Note that if you add a `.catch` to the promise later on - it will convert the ext from red to black as it will be "handled".

---

Note: you should always handle promise errors and strive to not have any unhandled rejections in your code :]

Answer (score 1):

Promise.reject always returns a promise with some rejected reason.You have to handle this by explicitly by using .catch

eg:

```
Promise.reject('test').catch(()=>{console.log('error is handled.')})
//new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("error")).catch(()=>{console.log('this is the test')})
```

Promise.reject is only something that rejects some situation.And If you want that something happen after this error throws then you have to do in the catch.

Comment: To expand, if you were to run `Promise.reject('test') instanceof Promise` in your browser's console, you'd get `true` -- Promises are asynchronous, so they won't run in a specific order without some control structure.

Answer (score 1):

An unhandled rejected promise does not actually throw an unhandled exception. If nothing handles the rejection, the default behavior tends to be log that an unhandled rejection occurred. It will not **currently** however crash your script/program by default (though that promise chain will die, and stop calling the next `then` handlers).

When running in NodeJS, the process object emits events when this occurs, which is documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
  // Application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

For example, you could respond to this by exiting the program with an error code.

When running in a web browser there is a similar event emitted by the window object that is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
  console.warn(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
});
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, the default behavior of this is planned to change in later NodeJS versions, and already there is a flag that can activate this functionality now since this MR https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/26599 that landed in v10

test.js

```
Promise.reject("test")

setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("alive");
}, 500)
```

**Current Default:**

```
$ node test.js
```

- Emits deprecation warning of unhandled rejection, but stays alive

**Future Default:**

```
$ node --unhandled-rejections=strict junk.js
```

- Converts unhandled rejection into an unhandled exception and exits the process.

Comment: " It will not however crash your script/program by default" - this is not required by JavaScript we _may_ change it in the future and we have been talking about it for a few years. I added a warning around Node 7 because of it. I am honestly not sure what the future holds although the warning literally says we will crash.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that's good to know. I hadn't noticed this somehow, but then I strive not to have unhandled rejections ;). I found a PR that adds support for changing the behavior in v10, will edit appropriately

Comment: You could change the behavior before Ruben's PR since Petka's PR in 1.3 that added the unhandledRejection event on the process :] However maybe =strict _is_ worth mentioning. It hasn't seen enough adoption for me to hold a strong opinion on it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to note the =strict option. For what it's worth I think making =strict the default makes a lot of sense, as I see no real difference between an unhandled exception and unhandled rejection. The tricky bit is whether we can be certain that there won't be a late attachment, but as I understand you've solved this by waiting for the promise to be garbage collected.

Comment: We reached consensus to do it on GC in May 2018 but lost consensus before acting on it on Jan 19. It has been a year since.